# Declare math operator

Tags: definition

I'm trying to create a command with which to write

```
\declaremathoperator{ABC}
```

to get

```
\def\ABC{\operatorname{ABC}}
```

I tried to implement it like

```
\def\declaremathoperator#1
{ \def\csname #1\endcsname{\operatorname{#1}} }
```

but it doesn't work: `Use of \csname doesn't match its definition.`

It seems to me that the solution, if it exists, should be based on writing `\#1`, but at the same time so that TeX first makes a substitution of `#1`, and only then would begin to consider `\` as the beginning of the command name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gain with respect to

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\ABC}{ABC}
```

is very little. And the proposed definition is ***very dangerous***. If it worked, you'd be able to say

```
\declaremathoperator{span}
```

and destroy your documents. You can do

```
\newcommand{\newmathoperator}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newmathoperator{ABC}
\newmathoperator{span}% <--- would give error
```

which would warn you in case the proposed command already has a definition. The `\expandafter` is necessary so `\DeclareMathOperator` sees the control sequence you want to define, rather than `\csname`.

Comment: Is there even a way to define a command inside another command, provided that the name of the new command is given by a string?

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov The same idea applies.